# Mapping Objects with attributes that may not exist

Tags: java, hibernate

Say i have two classes named TextList and Article.

```
public class Article() {
    public int a_id;
    public TextList text;
}

public class TextList(){
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    private String text3;
    private String text4;
}
```

And a table like this TEXT_ID :

```
text_id     text_type   text_content    article_Id
  1         text1       "Oh no"         1
  2         text3       "He has a dog"  1
  3         text4       "A Labrador"    1
```

As you could see, for **article_Id** 1 i have three texts (text1, text3, text4). This article doesn't have text type 2 and it's not a problem. The question is, how can i map the Strings in class **TextList** properly, meaning check the **text_type** column and maps to the attribute it belongs to? Also how can i map an attribute that may or may not exist in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the table layout you've shown, you could model that as follows which basically would mimic the table you described.

```
@Entity
public class TextEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "text_id")
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated
  @Column(name = "text_type")
  private TextType textType;

  @Column(name = "text_content")
  private string text;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "article_id")
  private Article article;
}

public enum TextType {
  TEXT1,
  TEXT2,
  TEXT3,
  TEXT4
}
```

However if the table schema isn't locked and you could use a slightly different alternative, I might suggest using an `@ElementCollection` that identifies a `Map<>` to accomplish the same thing.

```
@Entity
public class Article {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "article_id")
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  private Map<String, String> textMap;
}
```

This avoids having to define a text table entity and Hibernate would generate the table automatically that looks something like this:

```
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| textMap_key | textMap_value  | article_id |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| text1       | "Oh no"        | 1          |
| text3       | "He has a dog" | 1          |
| text4       | "A labrador"   | 1          |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

The `Map<>` key would be the text-type while the value would be the actual text content.  Hibernate would maintain the article_id relationship for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there no way to use the same model (meaning no Enum) and the same database ? I'm trying to Switch a working Programm to Hibernate so i would rather not changing the model of the table..

Comment: The `TextEntity` doesn't require that you use an Enum.  You could easily replace it with a `String` and use it as-is which would give you precisely the same table structure.  I tend to prefer Enum to keep specific finite data limited to expected values since a `String` can ultimately be "anything".

Comment: Hi, I've tried your Suggestion and still i have a new Problem. The Thing is this Table is used for more than 1 entity, say when the "text_type" = "info" (just an example), then the text doesnt belong to the class Article anymore, but to something else. Any Suggestion in this case ? Long Story short i want to check the value of column to decide which property of which class this row belongs to. Is that even possible ? Ty in advance.!

Comment: Is this _"something else"_ related to `Article` in anyway or is this table basically holding text associated to a variety of other tables using various FK relationship columns?